# Sql select query across server with login credentials

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to run a query on the server1 to get data from the server2. using "sp_addlinkedserver" i linked both the servers.

I cant able run a query from any of the server to access the other server data.

the error shows login failed for `sa`

Then i made same password for both the servers. Now i can able to run the query.

My question is, how can i run a query across server with different login credentials?

is there any way to pass the server2 login credentials along with the query?

Thanks for your interest

Comment: Please read this and confiqure your server, hope it helps [SQL Linked Server Query failed with “Login failed for user …”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/08/10/694657.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **sp_addlinkedsrvlogin** to pass the credentials to that server.

More documentation here: [sp_addlinkedsrvlogin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenRowSet To Select from the diffrent server with Credential

For example

```
INSERT INTO VMIntranetTest.dbo.TestTable (a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Age)
SELECT a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Age FROM
OPENROWSET('vmas400',
           'Server=192.168.1.2;Trusted_Connection=yes;user_id=INTRAIS;password=****',
           'SELECT FNAME, LNAME, AGE FROM BSLIB.dbo.SQLTSTF' ) as a
```

[OpenRowSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx)

Comment: Note:  this requires that component "Ad Hoc Distributed Queries" be turned on, using `sp_configure`.